# mistake or bug? freecodecamp

Tags: css, sass

I've been staring at this for way too long, I really don't see what I did wrong here

```
    @mixin border-stroke($val){
    @if $val == light {border-stroke: 1px solid black;}
    @else if $val == medium {border-stroke: 3px solid black;}
    @else if $val == heavy {border-stroke: 6px solid black;}
    @else {border-stroke: none;}
```

[image]

Comment: It says to set the ***border*** and you are not setting the ***border***

Comment: I think part of the problem, that code doesn't look like Javascript, please only use relevant tags.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mixin` is setting the (non-existent) CSS property `border-stroke` instead of just `border`.

Change it to this:

```
    @mixin border-stroke($val) {
    @if      $val == light  { border: 1px solid black; }
    @else if $val == medium { border: 3px solid black; }
    @else if $val == heavy  { border: 6px solid black; }
    @else                   { border: none; }
```